# Can I parameterize only the trust server certificate component of a connection string in an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, parameters, connection, ssl-certificate, connection-string

I'm configuring an SSIS solution in Visual Studio 2017 that sends data to an externally hosted SQL Server database and need to set the value in Connection Manager for that Destination Connection to Trust Server certificate = False. I also want to test the SSIS package against an internally hosted database but use Trust Server certificate = True for that Connection.

I have individually parameterized the database, user and password components of the connection string using the built-in options when you right click on the connection in Visual Studio and click parameterize, but there is no option in the drop down for Trust Server Certificate. Can I parameterise just that property without having to parameterize the whole connection string, so I can link it to an environment variable when executing the package from the Integration Services Catalog on the SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you parameterize the whole connection string in pieces into parameters/variables and piece it together in a final variable and use an expression on the  connection string to use the final variable.

Comment: Thanks! This let me do what I wanted, i.e. keep the existing parameters but use them, along with an additional parameter for Trust Server Certificate to build a connection string by referencing the parameters in an expression. Although I didn't put them into a variable first - is there any particular reason why I should have?

Comment: FYI I have 5 params, but only 2 expressions in the dest. connection properties:

**ConnectionString**  
`"Data Source=" +  @[$Project::DestinationConnectionOLEDB_ServerName] + ";User ID=" +  @[$Project::DestinationConnectionOLEDB_UserName] + ";Initial Catalog=" +  @[$Project::DestinationConnectionOLEDB_InitialCatalog] + ";Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=false;Use Encryption for Data=True" + ";Trust Server Certificate=" +  @[$Project::DestinationConnectionOLEDB_TrustServerCertificate] + ";"`

**Password**  
`@[$Project::DestinationConnectionOLEDB_Password]`